# Shift algorithm in a two-dimensional array of elements in an arbitrary direction?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I do the knockout effect in a turn-based game. Each time you knockout the target it should be moved in opposite direction from the  attacker for some cells. And if any other characters placed in new target position they should be moved and so on.

It looks like element shift algorithm in a two-dimensional array on arbitrary vector:

```
------------
|0 0 0 0 0 0
|0 1 2 0 0 0
|3 4 5 A 0 0
|0 0 0 0 0 0
```

For example `A` attack `5`:

```
------------
|0 0 0 0 0 0
|0 1 2 0 0 0
|4 5 0 A 0 0
|3 0 0 0 0 0
```

The `4` and `5` was shifted right for one cell and `3` player was shifted down.

Can you recommend some kind of algorithm that does something like that?

Comment: why goes `3` down, not up? is there any gravity in the game?

Comment: ```some kind of algorithm```- recursion? Beware of infinite loops when each move will trickle another one...

Comment: @NinaScholz down or up - on any free cell if here is no free cells on the shift direction.

Comment: @MichalStefanow yes, i understand that this may kind of recurcion. But can`t understand how to handle shift in right order.